# Django-storage using apache-libcloud to upload files to google storage as shared publicly

Tags: django, google-cloud-storage, django-storage, libcloud

I setup my django application to use google cloud storage, via apache-libcloud and django-storages.

my `LIBCLOUD_PROVIDER` looks something like this

```
LIBCLOUD_PROVIDERS = {
    'default': {
        'type': 'libcloud.storage.types.Provider.GOOGLE_STORAGE',
        'bucket': 'bucket-name',
        'user': os.environ.get('GCE_STORAGE_KEY'),
        'key': os.environ.get('GCE_STORAGE_SECRET')
    },
}

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'etc.utilities.storage.GSStaticBucket'
```

It seems to work fine when I run `./manage.py collectstatic` and files get uploaded successfully. But am looking for a way to control the files access control; right now it uploads all files as private and instead want them uploaded to be publicly accessible.

[image]

But as you see from screenshot above. The uploaded files are not flagged for "Shared Publicly"

Can someone advise please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [default object access control](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control?hl=en#defaultobjects) on your bucket to give public read access to newly-created objects.

[Apache Libcloud](https://libcloud.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) allows you to send extra headers with your request, and you can effect the same behavior by adding the [`x-goog-acl`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference-headers#xgoogacl) header to the upload request. Their docs don't show it, but it's analogous to their [S3 example](https://libcloud.readthedocs.org/en/latest/storage/drivers/s3.html#specifying-canned-acl-when-uploading-an-object).

However, it appears that django-storages's wrapping of libcloud doesn't allow for providing that data, so you'll likely have to rely on the bucket default object access control.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, exactly, unforunutely this is not implemented in django-storages so I had to override the class and pass extra on `_save` method. But your response helped me find it, thanks

Comment: Care to post your solution so other django folks can use it?